# Comparing US date to UK date

Tags: vba, date, excel

I'm using Excel VBA and want to verify 2 dates are the same.  On my macro, the user enters a date in the mm/dd/yy format (01/31/15).  When the macro runs, it opens a file submitted by a user in Europe.  On that sheet, there is a date field where the date is entered in the dd/mm/yy format (31/01/15).  I'm wondering if there is an easy way to compare these 2 dates to verify that they are the same.

I could convert one of the dates into the other format and then convert both to a date serical to see if they are the same.  I wanted to check and see if there was an easier way or a function that could do that.

Thanks for the help........

Comment: Have you tried just simply comparing them?  My understanding is the VBA ignores regional settings so when it brings that `DateValue` into a variable in VBA, it should convert it to same format.

Comment: IF the values being compared are truly dates, just compare them.  Dates are stored by Excel as the number of days since 1/1/1900 (or 1/1/1904).  The format is (should be) irrelevant.  If the dates are not really dates, but rather text strings, or improperly converted dates, that is the problem that should be solved, first.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the [MSDN Library has a converter `Sub`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834784%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

```
Function MakeUSDate(DateIn As Variant) As String 

   ' Do nothing if the value is not a date. 
   If Not IsDate(DateIn) Then Exit Function 

   ' Convert the date to a U.S. Date format. 
   MakeUSDate = "#" & Month(DateIn) & "/" & Day(DateIn) & "/" & Year(DateIn) & "#" 
End Function
```